Rigorous definition of the average value $\langle a^{*}(f)a(g)\rangle$ on Fock spaces for arbitrary states
One of the axioms of quantum mechanics states that a quantum state $\rho$ is a positive (hence self-adjoint) trace class operator with trace one. Given an observable $A$, the expected value of $A$ in the state $\rho$ is:
$$\langle A\rangle_{\rho} := \operatorname{Tr}\rho A$$
If $A$ is bounded, then $\rho A$ is also trace-class and the above formula makes sense. If $A$ is unbounded, however, one has to be a bit more precise in this definition.
Suppose I want to consider a one-particle space Hilbert space $\mathscr{H} = L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ and its associated (bosonic) Fock space $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}(L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3}))$. Let $\rho$ be a quantum state on $\mathcal{F}$. I want to make sense of the following object $\langle a^{*}(f)a(g)\rangle_{\rho}$, for $f,g \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$. However, both $a^{*}(f)$ an $a(g)$, and thus its composition $a^{*}(f)a(g)$ are unbounded operators on $\mathcal{F}$. Hence, it is not clear whether $\operatorname{Tr}\rho(a^{*}(f)a(g))$ is well-defined.
My question is: under what condition on $\rho$ is $\langle a^{*}(f)a(g)\rangle_{\rho}$ well-defined? In particular, if $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the number operator on $\mathcal{F}$ and I assume $\rho$ is such that $\operatorname{Tr}\rho \mathcal{N} < \infty$, is it enough to guarantee that $\langle a^{*}(f)a(g)\rangle_{\rho}$ is well-defined? Physically, it seems reasonable since I would be demanding that the average number of particles in the state $\rho$ is finite, but I am not sure how to prove using proper mathematics. Any help is welcome.

See e.g. section 7.2. here to start with...although this is only defined for self-adjoint observables, but if I had to guess (I haven't tried), I'd say that this generalizes.
